# Pandas dataframe query single quotes in a string argument

Tags: python, pandas

How can I escape the single quotes character in the string I want to search for?

Example:

```
strng = "King's palace"
df.query("fieldname == %s" %(strng))
```

This query is not returning data because of the quotes. Escaping is not helping.

Comment: does `strng= r"King's palace"` work?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are you expecting here? For instance just doing `df[strng]` will just work, can you post raw input data, your code and desired output

Comment: Sorry there is a change. I made a mistake

`subdf= df.query("fieldname == %s" %(strng))`

This is how I use in the code. This is iterated over a string array. When the string contains singlequotes it doesn't work.

Comment: Edit your question, also you failed to respond to does strng= r"King's palace" work?

Comment: The string value is coming from an array of string. So I think there is no option to give r before the string.

Comment: I tried giving this as `df.query(r'fieldname == %s' %(strng))`. It worked. Thanks Edchum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'fieldname': ['King\'s palace', 'Hilton']})

strng = "King's palace"
df.query("fieldname == @strng")
```

Output:

```
       fieldname
0  King's palace
```

Comment: how and why this works?

Comment: @benzkji my guess is that in the query method a parsing is made that takes care of properly managing special characters in variables.

Comment: thanks. but how comes the variable `strng` is inserted into the query? I mean `"fieldname == @strng"` is a string, and that's it? Or is this a feature in python that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried giving this as `df.query(r'fieldname == %s' %(strng))`.
It worked. 
Thanks Edchum.